# Is $S^n/(v∼−v)$ diffeomorphic to $\Bbb RP^n$?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

[$S^{n}/(v∼−v)$  is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{RP}^n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032094/to-show-that-sn-v-sim-v-is-homeomorphic-to-mathbf-rpn)

But,  is  $S^{n}/(v∼−v)$   diffeomorphic  to $\mathbb{RP}^n$?

If $n=1$, the answer is [yes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298879/showing-diffeomorphism-between-s1-subset-mathbbr2-and-mathbbrp1).

Comment: Yes, although for my definition of the standard smooth structures on both of these it is obvious that they are diffeomorphic (because the smooth structure on $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is inherited from the quotient map from $S^n$). What definition do you have in mind?

Comment: (note that if you don't define a smooth structure on source and target then the question is a little broken.)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, consider the smooth map:

$$f: \mathbb R^{n+1}-\{0\}\longrightarrow S^n, x\longmapsto \frac{x}{|x|}.$$

Let $\pi_2: S^n\longrightarrow S^n/(v\sim -v)$ be the canonical projection. This is also smooth.  In particular, the composite is smooth $$\pi_2\circ f: \mathbb R^{n+1}-\{0\}\longrightarrow S^n/(v\sim -v).$$

This induces a smooth map at the level of quotient:

$$\overline{f}: \mathbb R\mathbb P^n\longrightarrow S^n/(v\sim -v)$$

This is the unique map such that $$\pi_2\circ f=\overline{f}\circ \pi_1$$ where $\pi_1: \mathbb R^{n+1}-\{0\}\longrightarrow \mathbb R\mathbb P^n$ is the canonical projection.

The map $\overline{f}$ will be the desired diffeomorphism.